# Direct Email link com.salesforce.salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app

I am trying to get direct link to salesforce1 in the Email Tempalte but I am not abloe to do. I have tried with differnt ways.

I have tried with below URL:
com.salesforce.salesforce1://entity/view?entityId=(your ID here)
However this is also not working. Please let me suggest where I am wrong.

Thanks,
Manoj